# PHP PayPal payment verification / HTTP POST?

Tags: php, string, paypal, http-post

I am working on a software project and have written a validation system to help prevent theft of the software. I was reading back through the code, and found a huge "loophole" that could potentially allow the motiviated users to copy the program and install it without even contacting the activation server. So, I modified the program and the server to patch that up. Now, I need a PHP page that can check to make sure the user paid for the software, payments made using PayPal, then generate a random string. I then need the page to POST that random string to the validation server ( HTTP ) and listen for the response from the server. It will need to POST this parameter: Validator = [Random String] It will tell the page if the random string has already been submitted and to try another, or that it accepted the string. I would like the string to be numerical, but I think alpha - numeric would be better and give more options. I am pretty confident this can be done, but am not sure how to do the PHP part.

Comment: You'd be better off making your software worth buying. It's essentially impossible to lock down a PHP application, no matter how much you obfuscate or "compile" the code. A sufficiently motivated user WILL subvert/break/bypass anything you can install in the way of authentication/verification. That being said, just use CURL for your POST. Or file_get_contents with the appropriate stream setup.

Comment: The main application isn't PHP. PHP is just used to verify the user paid, then generate them a random string. I am aware that it is not possible to completely "secure" any kind of application, but I do believe steps should be made to at least make it harder to crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which PHP part?

You could generate a random string with [md5](https://www.php.net/md5).

To POST from a PHP script, just use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: Sorry... This is hat I need the PHP page to do:
    1). Verify that the user did pay the proper amount through PyPal.
    2). If the user paid, generate a random string, display it to the user and POST it to an HTTP server using this parameter: Validate = [Random String]
I am not a PHP programmer, but am learning. I do think I could find some examples using curl and md5 for random string generation, but how would the payment verification work?

Comment: PayPal's website has an example PHP script of validating payments through IPN. Here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code_ipn_code_samples

Comment: Thanks! Thank you everyone who helped!